# Intent.putExtra - How to send a string to the next activity?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

OK, I create a simple string from some data entered by the user. I now want this data to passed as a string (CSV like string) across to the next activity. In one example I have seen this:

```
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, string_to_be_sent)
```

But this throws an error saying EXTRA_MESSAGE isn't a value - ie. it is recognised by the intent. I think the example is outdated. What should I use to send a string? I have looked at documentation and found this:

```
public Intent putExtra (String name, String value)
```

But what would be the name of my value?? Anything I choose, or does it have to be a package name??
Thanks for the help  :)

Comment: You really need to do some basic programming tutorials.  EXTRA_MESSAGE is a variable which you have not defined anywhere.  From the user of upper case and underscore, by convention, it's a constant so I would expect to see something like `final string EXTRA_MESSAGE = "Name of string extra";`  This is a good example of why "copy paste programming" is not a successful strategy.  There is no known shortcut to learning.  You should also get into the habit of reading the documentation before asking basic questions. Reading the documentation for `putExtra` would tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: `EXTRA_MESSAGE` just is a Unique String tag, and you should use that to retrieve data from second Activity

Comment: I have. This is based off an example, which I have recognised to be outdated. EXTRA_MESSAGE is meant to be some form of int which the method recognises.

Comment: here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: ie. I have read docs and tutorials, they just haven't answered my question.

Comment: @Simon, the EXTRA_MESSAGE used to be a constant value, but is not anymore. I want to know what the updated value should be - docs.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)  What do you mean "used to be a constant value"?  It is up to you if it's constant or not but not being constant makes no sense.

Comment: I mean it used to be a value that the method recognised, when passed as a parameter, instead of a value that I made up. Look at this link, it was used here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: EXTRA_MESSAGE was meant to be a constant that the Intent.putExtra() method would recognise, but seems to be outdated and obsolete, I was wondering what the substitute today was, to send strings in PutExtra.

Comment: From that very page => `In order for the next activity to query the extra data, you should define the key for your intent's extra using a public constant. So add the EXTRA_MESSAGE definition to the top of the MainActivity class:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    ...
}`  If you read the documentation, it quite clearly states that it is whatever value you want to use as the key to the extra.  I repeat.  It's all clearly documented.

Comment: OK, you're right... Thanks for pointing that out and being patient with me... Sorry!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**First Activity** :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Variable Name",string_to_be_sent);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Second Activity** :

```
//Receiving data inside onCreate() method of Second Activity
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("Variable Name");
```

Comment: Yes this works, other people's answers will work as well, for future readers. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent intent= new Intent(currentActivity.this, TheActivityYouWant to Start.class);
intent.putExtra("SOME_KEY", "Sending");
startActivity(intent);
```

And for retrieving this in your other activity Do like this in your activity `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` which has been started.

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle != null) {
String your_extra = bundle.getString("SOME_KEY");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
intent.putExtra("anyNameYouWant", "desired string value");
```

Comment: Yes this works. I accidentally missed Extra on the end... oops, which is why I got the second error. Thanks!!

Comment: It was helpful, and most directly addressed my problem, but I thought the answer above was most helpful for future users. I normally will look at the accepted answer for help on other people's questions, so thought this would direct people to the right answer :)

Comment: I will never forgive T.T

Answer (score 1):

```
String product = "hellow"; 
    Intent myintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),view1.class);
    myintent.putExtra("product", product);
```

Comment: you also need to add code to retrieve your data 

String product = myintent.getStringExtra("product");

Answer (score 1):

In the sending activity:

```
 String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "Your string to be sent.."

    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, EXTRA_MESSAGE ); 
    startActivity(intent);
```

Then in onCreate method of receiving Activity:

```
    Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
    String stringtoBeReceived = bundle.getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

`EXTRA_MESSAGE` certainly means that it's a `static final String` value.

As the others answered how to use it, I would add that creating a `Utils` class will help you to maintain your code more flexible. I.e you can create a `Utils` class that will hold all your constant values.

```
final class Utils {
  private Utils(){}//avoid useless instantiation of the class
  private final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "extraMessage";
}
```

Now if you want to change the value of this String, you will just have to change this one and not go though all your classes/activities and search where you used this String value.

And you can just do :

```
myintent.putExtra(Utils.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "theMessage");
String extra = bundle.getString(Utils.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

Now if you want to change the value of `EXTRA_MESSAGE`, you will just have to modify it in the `Utils` class.